# How can I create one variable for coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, coordinates

Currently, if I want to make my TikZ images independant of coordinates, I use

```
\newcommand\AX{0}
\newcommand\AY{1}
```

Can I create one coordiante for one point? How can I access the x-part or the y-part if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\getX[1]{\expandafter\getX@i#1\@nil}
\newcommand*\getY[1]{\expandafter\getY@i#1\@nil}
\def\getX@i#1,#2\@nil{#1}
\def\getY@i#1,#2\@nil{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand\A{1,-1}
my coordinates: \getX{\A},\getY{\A}

\end{document}
```